# Timer1 on stm32f4

Tags: stm32, timer, hal-library

Im giving a try to stm32 after a long time programming on avr, and seems like im struggling with timer.  I want to use timer for handling freezes:

```
 HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim1);
while ((GPIOA->IDR  & GPIO_PIN_3) == 0x08) 
{
        Clk_h
    DWT_Delay(200);
    Clk_l
    DWT_Delay(200);
}
 HAL_TIM_Base_Stop_IT(&htim1);
```

In the code above im waiting when GPIO_PIN_3 will become in a low state. 
The thing is that its possible that it will stay high state forever, so i want to start timer1 and after 500ms it sohuld trigger interrupt. The problem is while loop catches 0 it tooks around 100us, and my timer configured with:

```
static void MX_TIM1_Init(void)
{

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig;
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig;

  htim1.Instance = TIM1;
  htim1.Init.Prescaler = 16799;
  htim1.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim1.Init.Period = 4999;
  htim1.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim1.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim1, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim1, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}
```

so it much more then 100us, but whatever it fires once , i dont know why. As i understand timer, after you start it, it should start count and when the value is reached it will trigger the interrupt. But here even if i immediatly start and stop the timer:

```
  HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim1);
 HAL_TIM_Base_Stop_IT(&htim1);
```

it will trigger once anyway. What i need is trigger interrupt function only when overflow on count register occures. 
Here is my  overflow function, its located on stm32f4xx_it.c:

```
void TIM1_UP_TIM10_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_UP_TIM10_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_UP_TIM10_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&htim1);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_UP_TIM10_IRQn 1 */
    sprintf(str123,"<<FAIL>>");
    CDC_Transmit_FS((uint8_t*)str123,strlen(str123));
  /* USER CODE END TIM1_UP_TIM10_IRQn 1 */
}
```

Comment: What do "Clk_h" and "Clk_l" mean ?

Comment: @LongPham its just some macros: #define Clk_h                HAL_GPIO_WritePin( GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_SET);
#define Clk_l                HAL_GPIO_WritePin( GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_RESET)

Comment: I don't use the HAL, but the timer 1 registers are preloaded so you need to issue an update event to load new values into them. Somewhere in the HAL (maybe Base_Init?) it will be doing this, which will result in the update interrupt flag being set. That is why the timer is firing when you enable the interrupts. You just need to clear the UIF in the SR register (write 1 to it - there is a HAL function somewhere for doing this) before you start the timer/enable interrupts.

Comment: Also if you have come from AVR, I would recommend not using the HAL. The timer is pretty straight forward to use, the HAL, not so much.

Comment: @Jon Could you be so kind, to show me exmaple of using registers for handling a timer as an aswer, i want to try it out

Answer (score 4):

I don't really like the HAL, so here is how to do what you want by just accessing the timer peripheral directly:

```
// SETUP STUFF:

// Enable the timer clock. I use the HAL for this
// as it adds the required startup delay. The code
// is pretty simple though.
__HAL_RCC_TIM1_CLK_ENABLE();

// Reset the control register. This gives us the 
// default operation which is counting up with no
// divider.
TIM1->CR1 = 0;

// Set prescaler
TIM1->PSC = 16799;

// Will generate interrupt when this value is reached
TIM1->ARR = 4999;

// The PSC and ARR values are currently in the preload
// registers. To load them into the active registers we
// need an update event. We can do this manually as
// follows (or we could wait for the timer to expire).
TIM1->EGR |= TIM_EGR_UG;

// Timer is now ready to use.

// POLLING OPERATION:

// Next we setup the interrupts. We should first clear
// the update interrupt flag in case it has already been
// set.
TIM1->SR = ~TIM_SR_UIF;

// Then we can enable the update interrupt source
TIM1->DIER |= TIM_DIER_UIE;

// Note: we also need to setup the interrupt channel on
// the NVIC. Once that is done the isr will fire
// when the timer reaches 5000.

// We can now start the timer running...
TIM1->CR1 |= TIM_CR_CEN;

while ((GPIOA->IDR  & GPIO_PIN_3) == 0x08) 
{
    Clk_h
    DWT_Delay(200);
    Clk_l
    DWT_Delay(200);
}

// ...and stop the timer when we're done
TIM1->CR1 &= ~TIM_CR_CEN;

// Note if we want to repeat the polling loop again we should
// issue another TIM1->EGR |= TIM_EGR_UG event as this
// resets the timer to zero.
```

Comment: Good work, beat me by a few minutes. Note that if you don't clear `TIM1->SR` again in the interrupt handler, you'd get endless interrupts. HAL won't do it for you if you don't use HAL :)

Comment: `PSC` is always buffered, but `ARR` is not (unless the `ARPE` bit of `CR1` were set, but you are clearing it).

Comment: @Jon okay, but how to controll interrupt, is that eny fucntion? or i can take berendi's function?

Comment: doesnt work either, i copied your code. I can see CNT is counting at the debugger, but unterrupt function doesnt triggers

Comment: @james_bk did you configure the NVIC?

Comment: @Jon i did it on Cube, i chose NVIC "TIM1update interrupt" in TIM1 settings. Maybe its again HAL problems, and it isnt enable it properly. Is it any register that enable NVIC?

Answer (score 4):

My solution would be almost identical to @Jon's, but I'd start the timer in one-shot mode, to avoid getting a second interrupt when processing the first takes too long. This way, no timer stop function is needed.

```
void TIM1_Init() {
    // edit: added clock and interrupt enable
    __HAL_RCC_TIM1_CLK_ENABLE();
    NVIC_SetPriority(TIM1_UP_TIM10_IRQn, 0);
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM1_UP_TIM10_IRQn);

    TIM1->PSC = 16799;         // prescaler
    TIM1->EGR = TIM_EGR_UG;    // generate an update event to load the prescaler
    TIM1->ARR = 4999;          // counter limit
    TIM1->SR = 0;              // clear interrupt status after the update event
    TIM1->DIER = TIM_DIER_UIE; // enable interrupt on update (overflow) event
}

void TIM1_Stop() {
    TIM1->CR1 = 0;             // stop timer by clearing CEN (and everything else) in CR1
    TIM1->CNT = 0;             // reset counter, so it will start from 0 at restart
}

void TIM1_Start() {
    TIM1->CR1 = TIM_CR1_CEN    // start the timer
        | TIM_CR1_OPM;         // in one-pulse-mode
}

void TIM1_UP_TIM10_IRQHandler(void) {
    TIM1->SR = 0;
    strcpy(str123,"<<FAIL>>"); // sprintf should not be used in an interrupt handler
    CDC_Transmit_FS((uint8_t*)str123,strlen(str123));
}
```

Comment: so if i understand interrupt will be lamost fired to TIM1_UP_TIM10_IRQHandler, because we dont have stop here. I need to not fire interrupt function, when app is not freezed on a looop

Comment: doesnt seem to work, TIM1_Start(); gives me nothing, when it sohuld trigger TIM1_UP_TIM10_IRQHandler

Comment: @James_BK Added code to enable clock and interrupts, and timer stop. If it still doesn't work, try lowering the timer period (`ARR`) value, in case your clock runs slower as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The following is for TIM2 but the same steps can be applied for TIM1

```
#include "stm32f401xc.h"  // chip title


int data = 0;

int main()
{

NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM2_IRQn); // Enable NVIC interrupt

RCC -> APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_TIM2EN;
RCC -> AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOAEN;

GPIOA->MODER = 1; // output_pp
GPIOA->ODR = 0;   // logic low

TIM2->DIER |= TIM_DIER_UIE; // enable interrupt
TIM2-> ARR = (uint32_t)0xff0;    // counter ceilling (max value the counter can has them start counting from the beginning)

TIM2-> PSC = 100;           // prescaler value
TIM1->SR = 0;               // disable all flags

TIM2-> CR1 |= 1;            // start timer



while(1)
{
    GPIOA ->ODR = data ;  // data is updated inside TIM2 ISR
}

    return 0;
}


void TIM2_IRQHandler(void) {
    TIM2->SR = 0;            // clear TIM2 ISR flag to not enter again once finished
    data = (1 ^ data) & 1;  // toggle the value of data 1 -> 0 -> 1 -> ...
}
```